# How do I create hidden fields in SalesForce Live Agent?

Tags: liveagent

We have a SalesForce Live Agent chatbox on our site that pre-fetches a handful of information when a user logs in. Some of those fields we would like visible like name, email address and phone number. Others, like their account number or account manager's email address, we want available for submitting the form but hidden. Is there a way to do this? Is there some functionality when creating the form I am missing or is this something I need to do with some extra CSS on the client side?

Comment: I think [extraPrechatFormDetails and extraPrechatInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_details.htm) can help here . With these parameters, you can send information to the agent and to your org beyond what’s shown on the pre-chat form. Also see this [related post](https://metillium.com/2021/12/hide-first-last-name-on-embedded-service-chats-prechat-form/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the extraPrechatFormDetails. With these parameters, you can send information to the agent and to your org beyond what’s shown on the pre-chat form.

From [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_details.htm),

```
  embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
  "label": "First Name",
  "value": "John",
  "displayToAgent": true
}, {
  "label": "Last Name",
  "value": "Doe",
  "displayToAgent": true
}, {
  "label": "Email",
  "value": "john.doe@salesforce.com",
  "displayToAgent": true
}];
```

> **displayToAgent**: Boolean
>
> Whether to display this label and value to the agent.

You could set the account number or account manager's email address values and make "displayToAgent": false in the extraPrechatFormDetails